# How to compare two lists using CLI

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, command-line-interface

I'm totally new to scripting, but would like to use Windows CLI compare two text files, list1.txt and list2.txt, each containing a list of values, and generate a new text file containing values that are found in one list but not in the other. I've been reading about Powershell, Shell, Batch files etc but cant seem to figure out the basics. Do I need to download anything to use these languages? Or how can I directly compare the files using the Windows CLI? Thanks.

Comment: That's very doable in PowerShell, which is preinstalled in windows 7+ and easily added in vista or less - look for some beginner powershell info on Google.  You're going to want to use Get-Content and Compare-Object, then Where-Object to select which difference indicator you care about.  Good luck!

Comment: Managed that, thanks! Maybe you could put your comment as an answer instead though so I can close the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very doable in PowerShell, which is preinstalled in windows 7+ and easily added in vista or less - look for some beginner powershell info on Google. You're going to want to use `Get-Content` and `Compare-Object`, then `Where-Object` to select which difference indicator you care about. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the regular Windows shell, just do:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in (list1.txt) do @find "%A" "list2.txt" >nul2>nul || echo.%A>>list3.txt
```

or if you put it in a batch file, double the % signs.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (list1.txt) do @find "%%A" "list2.txt" >nul2>nul || echo.%%A>>list3.txt
```

This will give you all lines in list1.txt that do not exist in list2.txt, and save them into a file called list3.txt.